# Move Base Publishing Y velocities

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've run into this strange behavior while trying to get my robot stack to run in gazebo. I've configured a turtlebot URDF with some 3D sensors and launching my pretty-generic ROS navigation stack configs. All of the sudden, move base is publishing only Y and theta velocities, no X.

I figure it must have to do with the URDF configs I changed or TF from the diff drive gazebo plugins, because I have not changed move_base in this development effort.

Any thoughts? I've become stumped here.

Example messages below:  (I can never figure out how to get the markdown to work in ros answers :( )

```
linear: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.714091062546


linear: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0


linear: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.401096045971


linear: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.000136807560921
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -0.800002932549
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283919/move-base-publishing-y-velocities/) by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8272 on 2018-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-28**:
To get the syntax highlighting working just copy and paste your code/terminal output into your question, highlight it, then click the *preformatted text* (`101010`) button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: Lies, it still happens. Something TF related?

Figured it out .

For the next weary soul: Turns out, for the diff drive controller, if you set it to base_footprint, it'll do some weird conversion or interpolation (?) and give you both X and Y components of a non-holonomic robot base.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-03-01**:
But that's not it! Also generally speaking, gazebo is not a happy camper with footprint transforms. Base Link made everyone happy which I'm a little confused by but I suspect TF isn't publishing this fast enough and gazebo has some assumptions in how you set it up.